# Кроссдоменные запросы Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular2

Как отправить кроссдоменный запрос на время тестирования приложения на Angular2.
Это только через сервер делается или на клиенте можно решить?

Comment: при кроссдоменном запросе сервер должен вернуть нужные заголовки

Comment: Просто думал, что в Angular это можно обойти на клиенте как-то

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду замокать запрос?